# How can I move grid to empty space after clicking?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am making a Puzzle Game in flutter and I want to move the block to empty space either on ots right,left,top ot bottom when I click on it.
What will be the logic behind it?
I tried a lot but nothing worked for me.
Please Help

[Here is the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xsvrc.png)

Here is my Code

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:puzzlegame/Views/grid.dart';

import 'package:puzzlegame/Views/headingText.dart';

import 'package:puzzlegame/Views/resetButton.dart';

```
class HomeView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<HomeView> createState() => _HomeViewState();
}

class _HomeViewState extends State<HomeView> {
  final List alphabets = [
    'F',
    'L',
    'U',
    'T',
    'T',
    'E',
    'R',
    'R',
    'E',
    'A',
    'C',
    'T',
    'I',
    'O',
    'N',
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const HeadingText(),
            Center(
              child: Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 100),
                  height: 600,
                  width: 400,
                  child: Grid(alphabets, onClick),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            ResetButton(reset),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void reset() {
    setState(
      () {
        alphabets.shuffle();
      },
    );
  }
  bool onClick() {
   
  }
}
```

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
class Grid extends StatelessWidget {
  List alphabets=[];
  Function onClick;

  Grid(this.alphabets,this.onClick);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: GridView.builder(
        gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 4,
          childAspectRatio: 5/5,
          crossAxisSpacing: 20,
          mainAxisSpacing: 20,
        ),
        itemCount: alphabets.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(7),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Text(
              alphabets[index],
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 134, 175, 134),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                  blurRadius: 6,
                  spreadRadius: 4,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```